# How to get data from other table using id

Tags: php, mysql

How to get data from other table?
I have table 'log' I want to select stud_id who has 'status_log' value of 'in' and 'out' and ''status' has a value of '0',and my question iwant to select student who has value '1' in 'year' from table 'student'.

this is my existing code.

```js
SELECT l1.stud_id FROM log AS l1
  JOIN log AS l2 ON l1.stud_id=l2.stud_id AND l2.status_log = 'out' AND l2.status = 0
  WHERE l1.status_log = 'in' AND l1.status = 0
```

this is the database table.
log

```
| stud_id | date_log  | time_log | ampm |status_log |status |
+---------+-----------+----------+------+-----------+-------+
| 123     |2015-08-19 | 07:38:34 | am   | in        | 0     |
| 123     |2015-08-19 | 07:40:34 | am   | out       | 0     |
| 5656    |2015-08-19 | 07:47:34 | am   | out       | 0     |
| 5656    |2015-08-19 | 07:47:34 | am   | out       | 1     |
```

student

```
 |cardcode | name      | year |section    |penalty_count |
 +---------+-----------+------+-----------+--------------+
 | 123     |martin     | 1    | A         | 0            |
 | 5656    |neptali    | 2    | A         | 0            |
 | 56577   |juan       | 1st  | A         | 0            |
```

thankyousomuch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will select `stud_id` with `in` or `out` value in the `status_log` and `status` of `0`, as well as `year` with `1` value in the student table.

```
SELECT a.stud_id, a.date_log, a.time_log, a.ampm, a.status_log, a.status, b.name, b.year, b.section, b.penalty_count
FROM log a
INNER JOIN student b ON a.stud_id = b.cardcode
WHERE (a.status_log = 'in' OR a.status_log = 'out') AND a.status = 0 AND b.year = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
SELECT st.cardcode as st FROM student INNER JOIN table as tb on tb.stud_id = st.cardcode WHERE
st.year = 1 AND tb.status_log IN ('in','out') AND tb.status = 0
```

WHERE clause specifies the following conditions : 
year is 1, status_log include `in` and `out` and status is 0

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table as tb on tb.stud_id = st.cardcode WHERE st.year = 1 AND tb.status_log IN (' at line 1

Comment: please replace table with log. (table name what you are using)

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'st.cardcode' in 'field list'

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT l.stud_id
FROM log l
JOIN student s ON l.stud_id=s.cardcode 
WHERE l.status_log IN ('in','out') AND l.status=0 AND s.year=1
GROUP BY l.stud_id;
```